# Thread synchronization on a C++ server

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, client-server, sfml

I've surfed the net for some days to find an answer to what's written on the title, but found only solutions that doesn't apply to my problem (examples are mutex, locking algorithms and some non blocking ones)...

My problem is:

I'm building a multiplayer videogame that I will use for my last exam in high school, using c++ and SFML, but I really cant find a way to synchronize all my threads. Currently, my program works with a "big" game thread, the thread that every cycle updates all the variables like player's positions, bullets etc and one thread per client, that handle the tcp-socket I/O with SFML (I could do it with standard sockets too but I like them), and every client thread has to read the current status of the game in order to send the data to the player.

But if the game thread is modifying the data while one of the client thread is reading it, this obviously results in a segmentation fault.
With X number of clients (basically, my objective is to handle all possibles clients limited on my machine power, so they can be 10 as well as 1000), how can I synchronize all their threads with the game thread?

If I use mutex or other blocking algorithms, there's no need to use more thread than one. At the end of the game cycle, I could just send and receive by all the clients the data. But this, slows everything, much more than the multithreading system does. One client with slow connection could slow everything.

What can I do? One big thread always active modifying everything that must not be stopped, and hundreds of other little threads that have to read the big-thread data in real time.

Thanks anyway!

If somehow I missed a question thread that explained this, please link that to me.

(P.s. The only important thing that I'm using with SFML is the graphic system, examples with winsock/linux ones are good as well. I'm using the c++11 threads)

Sorry for my english :c I did my best...

Edit: used html br's to end the line :P enter key doesn't work

Comment: Unfortunately this is way too broad a question for this site, but a few notes. Multiple threads modifying data etc won’t “obviously” result in a segfault. That’s completely different. Usually result is inconsistent data. As for synchronizing, reading data from clients or sending it to them won’t cause slowing down even if some connection is slow. Don’t use blocking IO and you’re fine, to an extent. Disconnect too slow connections if it seems there’s a problem. No need to have a thread per client.

Comment: One thread per client sounds like a lot tbh.

Comment: Does your keyboard have an Enter key ?  Learn how to use it.

Comment: I used enters :P I don't know why the message has been moved like this. I'll try to modify that now.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I know this is a pretty hard question, but I can't find answers T.T Can you please say precisely what I have to search? "non blocking synchronization c++" doesn't work...

Comment: You could always make your server single-threaded instead; then all your race conditions, deadlocks, and other multithread-related problems disappear.  You'd probably need to use non-blocking I/O to make sure your single thread doesn't get blocked in a network call.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the art of writing multi-threaded programs is learning to structure the program to minimize the *need* for synchronization.  One example:

Your "big game thread" (BGT) continually updates the game state.  Don't allow client threads to *ever* see that state.  Instead, have the BGT make a read-only *copy* of the game state at the end of each cycle.  Then, let the client threads look at the newest copy.

The clients still will have to lock and unlock some mutex in order to get a `shared_ptr` to the most recent copy, and there may also be some locking/unlocking in the `shared_ptr` machinery when each client is finished looking at the copy, but the total amount of time that any client will keep any mutex locked will be *much* less than if each client kept the entire game state locked while sending it out over the net.

Multi-threaded applications often do more copying than non-threaded applications, but it pays off.  In this case, the BGT pays the price to make a complete copy of the game state in each cycle.  But the payoff is, the client threads can all *simulataneously* access that read-only copy while the BGT *simultaneously* computes the next game-state snapshot.

Comment: That is my current solution. I created a list of game states, and the client threads read only the newest. Another thread deletes all the status that are not being used. This causes the game to overload alot, because every variable weight x times more than a normal variable. If there are 1000 thousand game states (it happens), one position weight 1000 times more. This doesn't sound good.

Comment: "Another thread deletes all the status that are not being used." I would not use a separate thread for that. I would write it so that each snapshot is deleted by the last thread that needed it.  In fact, I would not write the "delete" code at all because I'd let `std::make_shared<snapshot>(...)` and `std::smart_ptr<snapshot>` take care of it.

Comment: @Davide Re, "1000 game state [snapshots]" Are you saying that a client thread can get behind by a thousand frames? If that was true, I'd be looking for some kind of fast track/shortcut way for a client to catch up. (e.g., display at a reduced frame rate). I don't know anything about how your game is played, but a reduced frame-rate display might be a lot more playable than a display that lags the action by half a minute.